# dateRangePicker js single datePicker with time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to use date range picker with single date picker and time picker,
but the library does not support this option.
could you please help to tackle this problem, and the apply and cancel buttons don't appear

```
    // Single Date with time
    $('.single-date-time').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker:true,
        timePicker: true,
        applyClass: 'bg-slate-600',
        cancelClass: 'btn-light',
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'
        }
    });
```

Comment: You might be using plugin from https://www.daterangepicker.com If yes, have a look at the custom daterangepicker configuration url: https://www.daterangepicker.com/#config . Here single date & time is getting displayed properly. Regarding options "applyClass" it should be "applyButtonClasses" & "cancelClass" should be "cancelButtonClasses".

Answer (score 0):

Include these libraries on your project
 [moment.js](http://%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

[daterangepicker.min.js](http://%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

[daterangepicker.css](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20type=%22text/css%22%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css%22%20/%3E)

you have to add jquery libraries also

in your js file add following code

`$('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker();`

`$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
    endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
    locale: {
      format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
    }
  });
});`

and your Html code
`<input type="text" name="datetimes" />`

Answer (score 0):

I have tryed your code and setting into a function it it worked.(Libraries of bootstrap and daterangepicker and jquery)

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.single-date-time').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        timePicker: true,
        applyClass: 'bg-slate-600',
        cancelClass: 'btn-light',
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a'
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="single-date-time" name="test" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should look something like this :

```
<input style="width: 100%" date-range-picker id="daterange3" name="daterange3" class="form-control date-picker" type="text" ng-model="dateFilter"  options="optsSingleWithTime" autocomplete="off" required/>
```

Your JS code as follows:

//Get the single Date

```
$scope.optsSingleWithTime = {
singleDatePicker: true,
startView: 2,
minViewMode: 2,
opens: 'right',
timePicker: true,
startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(5, 'hour'),
locale: {
    label:'Custom Filter',
    applyClass: 'btn-green',
    applyLabel: "Apply",
    fromLabel: "From",
    toLabel: "To",
    cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
},
changeYear: true,
changeMonth: true,
maxDate:  date
};
```